# Acronym for ישראל (original source)

Tags: sources-mekorot, avot-patriarch-fathers, acronyms

Where was this insight originally brought down from?

> י = יצחק, יעקב
>  
>   ש = שרה
>  
>   ר = רבקה, רחל
>  
>   א = אברהם
>  
>   ל = לאה

The earliest work I could find was

[שני לוחות הברית](https://www.sefaria.org/Shney_Luchot_HaBrit,_Toldot,_Torah_Ohr.90?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi)

But I'm not sure if it was originally thought by this Great Rabbi [השל"ה הקדוש] (earliest work I could find with it mentioned) or was it brought down originally from somewhere else. I find this insight to just be too good to be overlooked and then discovered till 16 or 17th century although it is possible this Great Rabbi did indeed originally discover it. It was mentioned in other sources as well without a reference which is why I am also further questioning it. The Midrash Rabbah has numerous acronyms but I have searched there and not found this one in there.

Comment: How do you know this isn't the first reference?

Comment: It is possible it is the original idea of this Great Rabbi but there is room for doubt based on it being a compiled work and the reasons listed above. "The title page of the first edition states that the work is "compiled from both Torahs, Written and Oral, handed down from Sinai" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_Horowitz#Works

Comment: One reason to think it might be this Great Rabbi's original idea is that many sources are cited throughout this great work but the acronym for ישראל is not.

Comment: @ezra He said very clearly in the post "I find this insight to just be too good to be overlooked and then discovered till 16 or 17th century"